# Can't locate Jmeter\Bin on Mac to Install ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt

Tags: jmeter, performance

I have installed Jmeter by the homebrew method. For doing performance testing of mobile app, I need to install the `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`,
which I can't locate in the said `jMeter\bin` directory.
I searched by the name on my mac but unable to locate it.
I have followed all the steps are [mentioned here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

The file is being **generated** when you **start** JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), if you haven't started it ever - you will not find the file anywhere.

If you started the proxy server you should be able to find the `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`

- either under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation if you installed it manually from [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page
- or under `/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/x.x/libexec/bin/` folder if you installed JMeter using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (where `x.x` stands for JMeter version)

In case of more "exotic" JMeter installation or execution scenarios you can search your whole system from the [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)) application with the following command:

```
sudo find / -name ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt
```

---

Be aware of the alternative way of recording a JMeter test, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates, moreover it automatically detects any dynamic elements and performs correlation by adding the relevant Regular Expression Extractors. Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bash command `which` to find out the directory of a program.

```
which JMeter
```

[Check here for more details.](https://ss64.com/osx/which.html)

Comment: Hi Bharat, which command returns me /usr/local/bin/Jmeter as Jmeter path but when I try to search ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt  in the  /usr/local/bin
$ find ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt
find: ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt: No such file or directory

Comment: Per the tutorial doc you linked, it should be in jmeter/bin, i.e try `usr/local/bin/jmeter/bin`

Comment: Also, your usage of `find` was wrong. It should be `find [path to search in] -name [filename]`, i.e `find /usr/local/bin/jmeter/bin -name ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed Jmeter via `brew` you'll need to

```
open /usr/local/bin/jmeter
```

to get `jmeter` up and running.

which means you `bin` dir is at `/usr/local/bin`

On a side note, please consider using google, because this is one of the easiest ways to get answers.

Comment: yes..I am getting this directory from Terminal but find ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt is not successful. How to install this certificate to proceed ahead for mobile script recording for performance testing,

Answer (score 0):

Run the jmeter for the 1st time then cat the log file and you will see:

> $ cat jmeter.log
> ...
> Loading user properties from: /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.3/libexec/bin/user.properties
> Loading system properties from: /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.3/libexec/bin/system.properties
> ...
> JMeterHome=/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.3/libexec